# skrollr.js menu is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, skrollr

In my site I'm using skrollr.js for parallax effect. It is working fine in desktop but in mobile responsive menu is not scrolling because of the skrollr.

Comment: it may due to position , width ,height problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone after some research i my self go an answer

```
$( "class" ).click(function() {
    if($('class').length == 0){
        skrollr.init().destroy();
 $( "class" ).hide();
    }else{

        $( "class" ).show();
        skrollr.init().refresh();

    }
});
```